# (PHP) making string lowercase , with exception of first letter

Tags: php, string, exception, case

I've made a simple textbox which leads to a new page which echo's the input word by word (explode).
Now i want to to change all the letters to lowercase except the first letter (if this is inputted this way)

for example : Herman Archer LIVEs in NeW YORK -->  Herman Archer lives in new york

I hope you can help me out , thanks in advance!

Comment: try `ucfirst(strtolower("Herman Archer LIVEs in NeW YORK"));`

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted this question. Either mark it as a duplicate or just let it be. For someone starting to code this is actually a valid question. + voting to compensate.

Answer (score 19):

```
$str = 'stRing';
ucfirst(strtolower($str));
```

Will output: String

Answer (score 9):

Just do

```
ucfirst(strtolower($string)); //Would output "Herman archer lives in new york"
```

Also if you wanted every word to start with a captial you could do

```
ucwords(strtolower($string)); //Would output "Herman Archer Lives In New York"
```

Answer (score 2):

To make all chars of a string lowercase except the first, use:

```
echo $word[0] . strtolower(substr($word, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [mb_convert_case](http://php.net/manual/function.mb-convert-case.php), but you have to create an equivalent to ucfirst:

```
<?php 

    function mb_ucfirst($string) {

         $string = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($string, 1);
         return $string;
    }

    $string = 'hEllO wOrLD';        
    $string = mb_ucfirst(mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_LOWER));

    echo $string; // Prints: Hello world

?>
```